# Correctly parse dates with timezones in Python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, dst, pytz

I am working from Europe and I have a series of datetime that look like these:

```
 datetime(2016,10,30,0,0,0)
 datetime(2016,10,30,1,0,0)
 datetime(2016,10,30,2,0,0)
 datetime(2016,10,30,2,0,0)
 datetime(2016,10,30,3,0,0)
 datetime(2016,10,30,4,0,0)
 datetime(2016,10,30,5,0,0)
```

and so on for the entire day. I would like to convert them to UTC datetime which, in the end, should look something like this:

```
2016-10-30 00:00:00 + 02:00
2016-10-30 01:00:00 + 02:00
2016-10-30 02:00:00 + 02:00
2016-10-30 02:00:00 + 01:00
2016-10-30 03:00:00 + 01:00
2016-10-30 04:00:00 + 01:00
```

I used the following code to convert the timezones, but I get something that looks like this instead.

```
2016-10-30 00:00:00 + 02:00
2016-10-30 01:00:00 + 02:00
2016-10-30 02:00:00 + 02:00
2016-10-30 02:00:00 + 02:00
2016-10-30 03:00:00 + 01:00   
2016-10-30 04:00:00 + 01:00
```

The dates actually come from an Excel, but at the moment I am trying this to check if the conversion is correct.

```
import pytz
import datetime
from pytz.reference import UTC 

european = pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')
startdate = datetime.datetime(2016,10,30,0,0,0) 
hours = []

for i in range(3): 
   hours.append(startdate + datetime.timedelta(hours = i))
hours.append(hours[2])
for i in range(3,24): 
   hours.append(startdate + datetime.timedelta(hours = i))        

for i in range(len(hours)):
   hours[i] = european.localize(hours[i], is_dst = True)
   hours[i] = hours[i].astimezone(UTC)
   hours[i] = european.normalize(hours[i].astimezone(european))
   print(hours[i])
```

Update: Edited to make the question more clearer; hopefully
Update: Edited the time values in the code

Comment: Daylight Saving Time?

Comment: So basically it's taking `datetime(2016,10,30,2,0,0)` as the *second* occurrence of that local time, not the first. That seems just as "correct", it just happens not to be the way you expected it. The best way of avoiding this is to avoid using local times (which can be ambiguous or skipped) in the first place.

Comment: Yes @NinjaPuppy

Comment: (It doesn't help that you've only shown 4 lines of output in the last part... why is that?)

Comment: @JonSkeet The rest is the same. The most important time was the one at 3 am, because that is when the clocks turn back and the local time is 2. So everything afterwards is 2016-10-30T04:00:00 + 01:00, 2016-10-30T05:00:00 + 01:00 and so on until summer.

Comment: @sniffreed: It would really help if you'd provide a [mcve]. It's hard to work out which line is violating your expectations when a) we can't run the code; b) you've provided different amounts of output. As I said before though, the simplest way of avoiding this is to avoid using local times - what would you expect to happen at the DST change, when you give a value which doesn't exist?

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried.

Comment: It's still not clear where you're getting the output from. It would be handy if we could run the code and see the same output as you, without any tinkering. (I think you're nearly there, but you should end up with a `.py` file that is *all* that's required for us to see the same output as you.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, I print the output in the end, I have added that too. I am actually supposed to read these dates from an Excel, but I am trying the conversion on an iPython; hence no file.

Comment: How you're doing it in your real code doesn't make much difference in terms of what your sample code is... I assume you actually have an `import pytz` statement, for example? I'll try to help from here, but as I'm not a "native" Python dev, it makes things a bit harder...

Comment: @Jon Skeet import datetime, import pytz, from from pytz.reference import UTC  Thank you.

Comment: Okay, so I can now reproduce the results... but I suspect you're misinterpreting the output, which is the local time and UTC offset... so it all looks fine to me except the third line assuming that it's the *second* occurrence of 02:00 instead of the first. Will address that when I'm on the train... basically you want `is_dst=True`.

Comment: @sniffreed: Right, so all of that should be in your sample code. Again, I want to be able to copy, paste, run, without adding anything extra in. The less fiddling you expect other people to do for you, the more likely you are to get results...

Comment: You've now added `is_dst=true` into the question code, significantly changing the question. I was most of the way through writing an answer basically suggesting that, and you've made it pointless. This makes helping you extremely frustrating... I'm going to give it one last attempt, but if that doesn't work, I'm out of here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This local value:

```
datetime(2016,10,30,2,0,0)
```

is ambiguous. 2am happens twice on October 30th 2016 in Berlin - once at 2016-10-30T00:00:00Z (with a UTC offset of +2), then once again at 2016-10-30T01:00:00Z (with a UTC offset of +1).

Now with your updated expectations, you appear to be wanting the same input value to give a different output value the second time you call it... look here at your input:

```
datetime(2016,10,30,0,0,0)
datetime(2016,10,30,1,0,0)
datetime(2016,10,30,2,0,0)
datetime(2016,10,30,2,0,0)
```

Lines 3 and 4 are the same. But you expect output of:

```
2016-10-30 00:00:00 + 02:00
2016-10-30 01:00:00 + 02:00
2016-10-30 02:00:00 + 02:00
2016-10-30 02:00:00 + 01:00
```

Now lines 3 and 4 are different.

The only way I can see for that to work is to detect that you've just tried the same value, and this time pass `is_dst = False`. Fundamentally, you shouldn't expect to run the same code on the same input and it to psychically work out whether you really "meant" DST this time or not.

If you're genuinely running through all the hours of a day, then just work out the start time of the day in UTC and add an hour to *that* each time. Fundamentally, converting a local time to UTC is problematic precisely because of the potential for ambiguous local times (around the "fall back") and skipped local times (around the "spring forward").

Your question has changed several times so it's not *really* clear what your input data is (something to do with Excel, but quite possibly not the values you've shown us) but you need to work out what you want to do with a given local time... the `is_dst` flag allows you to express a preference for or against DST, but you can't expect `pytz` to know more about your context than you do.